# How to create the right view?

Tags: yii2

This my Controller-file with action:

```
public function actionFind()
{
    $query = Country::find();

    $countries = $query->orderBy('code')
        ->where(['country.code' => 'AU'])
        ->all();

    return $this->render('find', [
        'countries' => $countries,
    ]);
}
```

If I write in a view file:

```
<?= Html::encode($countries) ?>
```

PHP Warning - htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Bit, if I write in a view file:

```
<?= Html::encode($countries->code) ?>
```

PHP Notice – Trying to get property of non-object

What should I write in the view-file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$countries` variable is `array`. To display it, just simply use `foreach`:

```
<?php

foreach ($countries as $country) {
   echo Html::encode($country->code) . '<br>';
}
```

If you want to find one record, try using chain method `->one()` instead of `->all()` in controller, and then you can try display it in your way :)